# Javascript find if element exists in object value array

Tags: javascript

I have an object as follows -

```
var users = {
  room: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

How do I find if the 3 exists in the `room` array ?

[JS bin](http://jsbin.com/xozawifapuho/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf`:

```
var indexOfThree = users.room.indexOf(3);
if(indexOfThree != -1)
{
   var three = users.room[indexOfThree];
}
else
{
   console.log("not found");
}
```

it will return -1 if the element isn't found or else it's index in the array.

Comment: I want to check the entire array not just a specified position

Comment: its not a position it is searching for number 3 in the array

Comment: @Ajey - indexOf checks if a value exists in an array and returns the values index.